# how to change local language from view in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

so i worked in a multi language project in Laravel, so create my files in lang folder and when i change the language change successfully, but when i tried to change it from my view doesn't work, so this is my code to change the **local language :**

```
<li><a onclick="{{App::setLocale('fr');}};location.reload(true);">Francais</a></li>

<li><a onclick="{{App::setLocale('en');}};location.reload(true);">English</a></li>
```

Comment: You cannot call PHP from Javascript directly.

Answer (score 0):

`App::setLocale('en');` isn't generate js code for change language, it just set language for current application, that renders this view.

Comment: so how can i change it ?

Comment: it's not so simple, this might be another question

Answer (score 0):

`onclick` HTML attribute will not execute PHP Laravel code, do it in the controller, receive as parameter the language string `fr` or `en` and then do `App::setLocale($language);` and then return the View again, your view will render the correct language
:)